# I am getting error in this AngularJS code

Tags: angularjs

I have copied this code from O’Reilly Book of AngularJS
but Its not giving the same result as per the book .
Problem with this , Its not getting binded with controller's models

```
 <html ng-app>
    <body>
    <form ng-controller="StartUpController">
    Starting: <input ng-change="computeNeeded()"
    ng-model="funding.startingEstimate">
    Recommendation: {{funding.needed}}
    </form>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    function StartUpController($scope) {
    $scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0 };
    $scope.computeNeeded = function() {
    $scope.needed = $scope.startingEstimate * 10;
    };
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your angular file, try this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app>
    <body>
    <form ng-controller="StartUpController">
    Starting: <input type="number" ng-change="computeNeeded()"
    ng-model="funding.startingEstimate">
    Recommendation: {{needed}}
    </form>
    

    <script>
    function StartUpController($scope) {
    $scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0 };
       $scope.computeNeeded = function() {
         console.log("Hai");
         $scope.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
      };
    };
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: We can define controller as function also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912287/app-controller-vs-function-in-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

use `this`ie,
`this.funding` like that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912287/app-controller-vs-function-in-angular-js Try like this

Answer (score 0):

Issue with the way using ng-app with angular1.2 version.
In angular1.2, once you have added ng-app directive with  tag, you can directly inject function constructor to ng-controller. 
Which is you are doing right now but using angular1.4 version. With angular1.4, you will have to create angular module first then register your controller
with that module. Once you do it then only you can bind controller with ng-controller.

**Angular1.2 way:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app>
    <body>
    <form ng-controller="StartUpController">
    Starting: <input type="number" ng-change="computeNeeded()"
    ng-model="funding.startingEstimate">
    Recommendation: {{needed}}
    </form>


    <script>
    function StartUpController($scope) {
    $scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0 };
       $scope.computeNeeded = function() {
         console.log("Hai");
         $scope.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
      };
    };
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Angular1.4 or + way:**

```
<html ng-app='mainApp'>
<body>
<form ng-controller="StartUpController">
Starting: <input ng-change="computeNeeded()"
ng-model="this.funding.startingEstimate">
Recommendation: {{this.funding.needed}}
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('StartUpController', function($scope){

$scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0 };
$scope.computeNeeded = function() {
$scope.needed = $scope.startingEstimate * 10;
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the ng-model from this.funding.startingEstimate to just funding.startingEstimate and similarly for the interpolated variable (whatever is put inside {{ }} )

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the below ..it will work... you need to define ng-app name and make change in your js controller...

<html ng-app ="My-app">
    <body>
    <form ng-controller="StartUpController">
    Starting: <input ng-change="computeNeeded()"  ng-model="funding.startingEstimate">
    Recommendation: {{funding.needed}}
    </form>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    var app= angular.module("My-app", []);
    app.controller("StartUpController", ['$scope',  function($scope) {
    $scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0,  needed:1};
    $scope.computeNeeded = function() {
    $scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
    };
    }]);


    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```