# AngularJS When to Use Controller-level named functions?

Tags: angularjs, function, controller, named

Looking through tutorials and others' code. I don't understand why on some controllers a named function is used and on some there is no name?

eg. name is used on function

[image: named function]

eg. name is not used on function

[image: name not used]

My question is basically the same as the duplicate listed but the answer on my question I feel is a better answer than in the referenced "duplicate post."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First onee will create global namespace, which can be accessed globally

```
eventsApp.controller('CookieStoreSampleController,function CookieStoreSampleController($scope,$cookieStore){
});
```

This way of declaring controllers in **many examples** but that shouldn't be used in **applications**.

Second one scopes the Controller to that module instance which uses the array notation that will survive minification.

```
eventsApp.controller('LocaleSanpleController,function($scope,$locale){
});
```

Comment: I see, so because the function is named in the first example, other modules are basically able to access it?

Comment: yes, check this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912287/app-controller-vs-function-in-angular-js